# tooltip.pointFormat appearing as nil in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, highcharts

I am using highcharts basic column type graph for displaying data in graphs in my vue app. But I am facing an issue that series.name doest show the name of the first value for data. Below is the code and the screenshot of the issue. Please help me find where I am going wrong.

I have added a debugger and displaying the response I am getting. Please check.

```
<script>
  import {Chart} from 'highcharts-vue';

  export default {
    components: {
      highcharts: Chart
    },
    data: function() {
      return {
        chartOptions: {
          chart: {
            type: 'column'
          },
          xAxis: {
            categories: [],
            crosshair: true
          },
          yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
              text: 'Reporting'
            }
          },
          legend: {
            enabled: false
          },
          title: {
            text: ''
          },
          tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
            pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
              '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y}</b></td></tr>',
            footerFormat: '</table>',
            shared: true,
            useHTML: true
          },
          plotOptions: {
            column: {
              pointPadding: 0.2,
              borderWidth: 0
            }
          },
          series: [{
            name: '',
            data: []
          }]
        }
      }
    },
    created: function () {
      this.fetchReports();
    },
    methods: {
      fetchReports: function () {
        var that = this;
        url = '/my_views/reports.json'
        this.$axios.get(url)
        .then(response => {
          that.chartOptions.xAxis.categories = response.data.dates;
          that.chartOptions.series = response.data.series;
          debugger
        });
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

The data I am getting as response is as below:

response.data

```
=> {series: Array(3), dates: Array(4)}
```

response.data.series

```
{data: [0,2,1,0], name: "Wills"}
{data: [0,0,1,0], name: "Vicky"}
{data: [0,6,1,0], name: "Jamie"}
```

The issue here is that the in the series.name for pointFormat in tooltip appear as nil for the just the first value for rest the name show up just as in the picture below. Please help me find where I am going wrong.

[image]

Comment: Looks pretty weird. Have you tried to assign an empty array into the series before fetching the data? I mean `series: []` instead of `series: [{ name: '', data: [] }]`

Comment: @daniel_s inside the fetchReport method?

Comment: I meant the `chartOptions` object.

Comment: @daniel_s yes I tried that. But still the same issue

Comment: Would you be able to provide me with the minimal example (even with the fetch option replaced with the setTimeout or something), where the problem is noticeable? Unfortunately, I'm not able to reproduce the issue.